# How to move all labels in Form1 programmatically in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am trying to move all the labels located in Form1.  I can move a specific label, but how to loop and move all labels?  Thank you for any help and advise.

Move a specific label:

```
label1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

This wont work:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
for (int i = 0; i < f1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    f1.Controls[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all of the controls but you need to check what type of control it is in order to see if it is actually a label. The code below should work, the `as` keyword will result in `labelControl` being null if `ctrl` isn't actually a label

```
//Form1 f1 = new Form1(); // Removed, using this means you're calling from within the control you want to change already.
foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    var labelControl = ctrl as Label;
    if (labelControl == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    labelControl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried it? I don't know why for me does not work.

Comment: I created a new winforms app and tried it there, instead of Form1 f1 = new Form1() though I tried it in the form itself using `foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls)` instead. When you say it does not work, could you be more specific, what error/behaviour are you getting?

Comment: Ok, now foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls) instead of foreach(var ctrl in f1.Controls) WORKS! :-)  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. =) I'm guessing you were calling this code within the Form itself? If this is the case then when you called `Form f1 = new Form1();` you were actually creating another instance of the form and then moving the labels on that, but because that isn't the form that's being displayed you weren't seeing any changes. Using `this` within the Form code itself refers to the currently instantiated form.

Comment: Yep that is the essence of the problem. I missed that because the method names are not provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the is qualifier to find out if the control is indeed a label

```
//Form1 f1 = new Form1(); as pointed out this is not needed your are already on the right instance. doing new creates a new instance
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (Controls[i] is Label){
        Controls[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is not in the if statement but how to reference all label and more them.

Comment: you already have the for next in your question. That works too. The point is that you need to know if the child is a label yes or no. That part was missing and I simply completed the missing part.

Comment: If you try my code with your line of code, it works?

Comment: If you fix the compiler error that you have, yes it should work.Your closing } is an opening {, the compiler will not like that. But the for next loop is also fine. doing an 'as Label' works, checking first via 'is' also is fine. There's multiple ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: I do not have any compiler error, "This not work" (from my post) = does nothing.

Comment: you do have a compiler error, the very last character is a {, but i fixed it for you

Comment: Skip the if statement, the line f1.Controls[i].Location = new Point(0, 0); does not work.  Please see Neil solution, it works.

Comment: most likely because you new up a new form instance right within your own form method. So that would mean that for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    this.Controls[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
} works just as well. But you are happy with a solution, so you that is fine.

Comment: Well, I am not new in winforms and you haven't provide any workable solution.  So, if you have an alternative solution I would be very glad to test and if works to thank you.

Comment: I updated my alternative solution which is based on your for next solution which as i said should also work.